# Little Active record views updating

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord

I need little Active record help. I am trying to update page views which i store in database. Each time post() function runs, add +1 . Here is my code:

```
  public function post($id) {
 if($id == NULL){
 redirect('blog');
  }

 else{

 $this->db->where('entry_id',$id);
 $this->db->set('views','views+1');
 $this->db->update('entry');
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your code like this for example:

```
public function post($id) {
 if(!isset($id) || (int) $id<=0){
 header('Location: /blog');
  }

 else{

 $this->db->where('entry_id',$id);
 $this->db->set('views','views+1');
 $this->db->update('entry');
}
```

Mark the `header('Location: /blog')` - you should put here your real server path to the blog.
If you use a custom redirection function, like your `redirect()` then check if the is an output before calling her. Header redirection only works if no other output is sent to the browser before invoking it.

Comment: I had to put  $this->db->set('views','views+1',FALSE); it work now thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  public function post($id) {
 if($id == NULL){
 redirect('blog');
 }

 else{

 $this->db->where('entry_id',$id);
 $this->db->set('views','views+1',FALSE);
 $this->db->update('entry');
```

FALSE turns off Active record escaping,by default it ignores +1.